# Skip stylesheet line when open a file - vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

How can I skip these the css line below when I open an xls file using vba?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.0.36.41/woowtime/assets/resources/css/print.css" />
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Attendance Report</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  .....
```

Everytime open file function run, it takes long time to check the print.css and I've notice its caused by the link is unreachable.
Although it's easy if I delete the link line and save it, there are too many files that will be processed and it will take a time too

Is there any solution around this?

Comment: What do you mean by *when I open an xls file using vba?*

Comment: When open file function is run,
`Workbooks.Open(fileName, True, True)`